# How is OkHttp performing parallell HTTP Requests with seemingly synchronous HTTP connections, without the use of threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, okhttp

I've done some performance testing with the [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library and found it to be great. It did 80 requests to http://httpbin.org/delay/1, which deliberately pauses 1 sec for each request, in 4.7s on my HTC One phone. I've looked at the code and I'm trying to find out *why* it is so fast. The developers (Square Inc) advertise Connection Pooling and Async calls, both which I believe contribute to the good performance.

I come from the .NET world and in .NET 4.5 you have a true async HTTP library with an Async [GetResponse-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158912.aspx). By yielding the thread to the OS while waiting for the response, you free up resources to initiate more HTTP requests, or other stuff. The thing is I cannot see the same pattern with OkHttp (or any other HTTP library for Android I've looked into). So how can I  still execute 80 1-second-request in 4 seconds? It's not thread-based, right? I'm not firing up 80 (or 20) threads?

To be specific, in [com.squareup.okhttp.Call.beginRequest()](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Call.kt), I see no yielding of the thread between the `sendRequest` and `getResponse` calls:

```
if (canceled) return null;

try {
    engine.sendRequest();

    if (request.body() != null) {
        BufferedSink sink = engine.getBufferedRequestBody();
        request.body().writeTo(sink);
    }

    engine.readResponse();
} catch (IOException e) {
    HttpEngine retryEngine = engine.recover(e, null);
    if (retryEngine != null) {
        engine = retryEngine;
        continue;
    }

    // Give up; recovery is not possible.
    throw e;
}

Response response = engine.getResponse();
```

So again, how is making 80 "parallell" calls possible?

I don't *need* to know this in order to use the library, but async programming interests me and I'd really like to understand how OkHttp/SquareInc has solved this.

Comment: Are you issuing the requests one after the other or all at once? If it is one after the other then this *must* take >80s. If all at once then it can go arbitrary fast down to 1s. So how many threads are you usign to issue calls?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I did some testing myself by linking the OkHttp source into my project and injecting logging into the core request class - Call.java. What I found was that OkHttp indeed uses a thread for each call and does *not* yield while waiting for the response as I wrongly assumed. The only reason it is faster than for instance Volley, is that Volley has hard-coded a thread limit of 4, while OkHttp uses `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`Dipatcher.java` line 58):

```
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), Util.threadFactory("OkHttp Dispatcher", false));
```

Here is an exerpt of the LogCat log when I queued and excecuted 80 requests "asynchronously":

```
05-31 12:15:23.884  27989-28025/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Starting request 1
05-31 12:15:23.884  27989-28026/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Starting request 2
05-31 12:15:24.044  27989-28199/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Starting request 79
05-31 12:15:24.054  27989-28202/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Starting request 80
05-31 12:15:25.324  27989-28025/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Getting response 1 after 1436ms
05-31 12:15:26.374  27989-28026/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Getting response 2 after 2451ms
05-31 12:15:27.334  27989-28199/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Getting response 79 after 3289ms
05-31 12:15:26.354  27989-28202/nilzor.okhttp I/OKH﹕ Getting response 80 after 2305ms
```

The third column on format `xxxxx-yyyyy` indicates process id (x) and thread id (y). Notice how each requests gets its own thread and how the same thread handles the response. [Full log](http://pastebin.com/V9n7NDvb). This means that we have 80 blocking threads while waiting for responses, which is not how *true* async programming should be done.

In OkHttp / Square Inc's defense, they never claim to have true end-to-end async HTTP communication, they only provide an async interface to the consumer. Which is fine. And it also performs well and does a bunch of other stuff. It is a good library, but I misinterpreted it for having true async HTTP communication.

I have since understood to look for the keywords "NIO" to find what I'm looking for. Libraries like [AndroidAsync](http://koush.com/AndroidAsync) and [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) seems promising.

Comment: Just worth noting that you shouldn't compare Volley to OkHttp. You should be using Volley on top of OkHttp.

Comment: When you call enqueue, it checks the max total and per host requests. It then adds the request to a queue or executes it directly. See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.java#L109

Comment: also a .net dev new to java & if i hear async immediately assume IO Completion Ports (windows) and WHATEVER / POSIX AIO (linux)? and was wondering what okhttp3's docs mean with "responses are processed on the request thread" (WTF?) and how that worked with the RxJava call adaptor (which takes a RxScheduler). finally found this line https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/28d350d99430c87b4ada7d1aa9e08c96884cb388/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java#L171 and boom..they sync call in rx, using scheduler in place of okhttp3 dispatcher

Comment: which is not how true async programming should be done.

Answer (score 17):

OkHttp doesn't use async sockets at this time. If you're using the async API with `enqueue()`, the `Dispatcher` will spin up multiple threads and make multiple concurrent requests. If you use the same `OkHttp` client for all requests it will limit itself to 5 connections per host.

Comment: If OkHttp limits itself to 5 connections per host, how do you explain that I got 80 replies from a host that always waits 1 second before responding, in 4.7 seconds?

Comment: @JesseWilson I guess this 5 requests per host works only if you don't manually set the different value via `setMaxRequestsPerHost()`?

Comment: Exactly. You can set whatever limits you want.

Comment: 5 connections actually refer to Idle Connections. The library itself doesnt limit the number connections that can be spawned using a single okhttpclient instance https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.java#L89